# FK column name messed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

So, I'm having my first in experience with Ruby on Rails. This is the second month, but somethings are still kind weird to me. In some cases I can do:

```
link.url = url
```

Where the Class Link has a FK to the Url Class. But in some cases, if I do:

```
equipment.category = category
```

The Rails start to complaining, saying:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `equipment_id`
```

Why this happen? Every time I had to do it some changes in the tables about references I did:

```
add_reference :equipment, :category, foreign_key: true
```

So how can I do all Classes/Table behaviour like the first example?

**EDIT 1:**

My schema for Category and Equipment is this:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "equipment", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_equipment_on_category_id"
end
```

**EDIT 2**
The associations in the classes are this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    has_many :equipment
    ...

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    has_one :category
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your `db/schema.rb` and how you've set up the association in your `Equipment` model? I'd expect the name of that model's table to be `equipments` (plural). If so, your migration statement should be `add_reference :equipments, :category, foreign_key: true`.

Comment: The name of the table, actually, is just `equipment`. I will edit the question so I can show the schema.

Comment: Thanks for including the schema. (But please do share code as text, not images.) Can you also show the `has_one`/`belongs_to` associations in the models?

Comment: I added the associations and also edited the image. Thanks for the tips ;)

Comment: model `Equipment` will never map to table `equipment` by default, according to rails convention(model name is singular, table as plural), unless you have explicitly specified with `self.table_name = "equipment"` in `Equipment` model.

Comment: also, it needs to be `belong_to :category` in `Equipment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `belongs_to` for the class that has the foreign key, sp:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    has_many :equipment
    ...

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    belongs_to :category
    ...
```

You might also run into some trouble because `equipment` is [an irregularly inflected noun](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb#L70)—it's its own plural in Rails. Using that kind of word for tables/models often involves to trial and error for me, and may ultimately be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I renamed with a migration the table `equipment` for `equipments`, but now Ruby is saying: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'equipment'
`

Comment: Yeah you may need to tell the `Equipment` model to look for the table name `"equipments"`. By default it will look for a table called `"equipment".pluralize`, which just evaluates to `"equipment"`. Do this in the model: `self.table_name = "equipments"`. (Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) The simplest route (all else equal) is to choose a different name altogether.

Comment: Using a table called "equipments" defeats both the purpose of the inflector and exhibits the poor English the inflector is designed to prevent. The fact that you have to add extra configuration to support broken English makes it a very bad idea, IMHO.